# How can I prevent the generic app icon from showing?

Tags: android

I use a Nexus 6P (Oreo) and a Pixel 2 (Pie). I've seen this behavior on both. I've even seen it once briefly for Google Maps.

Sometimes, instead of the actual app icon, I'll see the generic Android head on a green background. It happens in the app drawer, on the home screen, or in app switcher. It's random, rare and hard to reproduce, and it happens briefly. I might be scrolling through the app drawer, suddenly realize my app's icon was wrong, scroll back to look at it--and it looks right. But every other time I scroll through the app drawer the icon is fine.

I can't see anything wrong we're doing with our app icon, and it happens rarely. But today I saw it happen (briefly) for Google Maps, which makes me wonder if it's a Google bug.

Any more insight on this issue? Or if it is something I can control, what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Edit: managed to get a screenshot of it in action. In this case it's from the app switcher (ignore the colored background around the green icon). As I noted though, it can happen on the home screen or in the app drawer, and it's not always limited to my app. In this case, the next time I used the app switcher, the normal app icon appeared, so it's quite random.

[image: generic app icon]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `all-dpi` xml file from `res > mipmap > ic_launcher` and `res > mipmap > ic_launcher_round` or create custom xml for your app icon. (I would just suggest removing it.)

[Here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/vectordrawable-adaptive-icons-3fed3d3205b5)'s how you can make your own adaptive icon.

Comment: The default app icon is not in the app. The default app icon is different from this image we are seeing. And if we were using the default app icon, the problem would be consistent, not as rare, random and ephemeral as it does now.

Comment: @ChadSchultz post image of what you are seeing.

Comment: Updated original post with image.

Comment: Have you tried to remove or make custom adaptive icon of your app as I said in my answer? I am pretty sure that's what making your icon look like this as Pixel and Nexus with Oreo have this "Tear Drop" icon style as default. Either create your own adaptive icon or remove xmls I suggested in answer above. Please try it and tell me if it works or not.

Comment: We are already using adaptive icons with custom XML files. No all-dpi XML file.